# PHPMailer sending random number of emails. How do I interpret this debugging output?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been trying to stop extra emails being sent. Updated to the current composer version today 6.x.x to see if it would help.

After reading other posts on this website and elsewhere, I added 
    $mail->ClearAllRecepients();
to the phpmailer code.  But I've either placed it in the wrong location or it isn't solving the extra emails being sent.

You can see from the debugging info that each of the emails were sent at a slightly different time, less than 1 second apart.

I need some guidance on how to interpret this debugging info to identify another way to fix the issue.

Here is my code which is based on the example available at packagist.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                     // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->isSMTP();                                                   
    $mail->Host = 'outlook.office365.com';       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                      // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'no-reply@website.com';     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $EMailPW;            // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                   // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                           // TCP port : tls 587 or ssl 465
    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@website.com', 'DO NOT REPLY');   

    $mail->AddAddress("h@the.com");
    $mail->addBCC("t@the.com");
    $mail->addBCC("me@com.com");

    //$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $emailinfo = new Emaillist();
    $emailinfo->load($link,$v[number]);

    if($v[type] == 25){ 

        $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML                       
        $service_notice = "info\n";

    }else{

        $mail->isHTML(true);                                 // Set email format to HTML                      
        $service_notice = "<p>info";
    }


    $myEmails = $emailinfo->getEmails();


        if(is_array($myEmails)){
            foreach($myEmails as $myEmail){
                $mail->AddAddress($myEmail);
            }        
        }else{
            $mail->AddAddress($myEmails);
        }                    

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                    

$debug = '';
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
$GLOBALS['debug'] .= "$level: $str\n";
};    
        $mail->Subject = "email subject";

    $mail->Body = $service_notice;

    $mail->send();
    $message .= '<h4>Confirmation Email sent.</h4>'; 

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();                    

$mailfile = 'phpmailer_log1.csv';
file_put_contents($mailfile, $debug, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Still seeing 1-4 emails when only 1 should be sent.

```
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email1@email.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email2@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email3@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email4@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<my@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 12:23:53 -0600
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: email1@email.com, email2@email, email3@email
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Sams HSC - DO NOT REPLY <no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Email Subject
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <zRteVwuqed9mzxSYv7kYzY6psx7Wvzy7zj2BOkIzq4@www.website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <p> line of info
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email1@email.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email2@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email3@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email4@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<my@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 12:23:56 -0600
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: email1@email.com, email2@email, email3@email
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Sams HSC - DO NOT REPLY <no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Email Subject
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <J1x2LuBKaCh1QHj3MxUM2hjFbO3k70pyCuV5Mbs1I@www.website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <p> line of info
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email1@email.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email2@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email3@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email4@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<my@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 12:24:01 -0600
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: email1@email.com, email2@email, email3@email
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Sams HSC - DO NOT REPLY <no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Email Subject
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <0pCMiMpKlyKVK0zLh2CjKn50oNpuyGlK9pzbDJQM8@www.website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <p> line of info
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.website.com
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email1@email.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email2@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email3@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<email4@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<my@email>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 12:24:04 -0600
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: To: email1@email.com, email2@email, email3@email
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Sams HSC - DO NOT REPLY <no-reply@website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Email Subject
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <93733OGtyxVygc7xXO6cDMoQwOuvzpZ7MFerWBLA@www.website.com>
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: <p> line of info
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: 
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: .
1: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

Comment: By "extra" do you mean "duplicates?" Please clarify.

Comment: Other than the SERVER: Date: they were sent they appear identical to me.  The SERVER: Message-ID: is also different

Comment: Right, different messages would end up having different message ID's even if it was duplicate content. Are you sure you don't have duplicate email addresses in your `$myEmails` array?

As a test, instead of actually emailing them  out, send the text of the emails to a log file and then examine that. Then you can determine whether there's something in your code or whether PHP Mailer is having an issue.

Comment: Yes, that data has no dups, already checked that.  I made a log table and started writing the unique identifier for each record to it, indicating it was already emailed.  Thus far the dups have stopped.

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward - you're calling `addAddress` a bunch of times, so it sends to all those addresses, as you're asking it to

Comment: @MikeVolmar - If you find the exact reason, the post the solution as an answer and mark your own question as solved.

Comment: @synchro not sure what you mean. Multiples get sent randomly, not all the time, not even all the time to the same recipient.  And recipient may or may not have more than 1 email assigned, which seems to have no effect.  I have even seen more than 1 email sent when hitting test email script with only 1 or 2 hard coded recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to stop multiple copies of the emails being sent by logging a unique identifier after the first send event and checking the log prior to every send. The function call simply counts the number of times the unique identifer is found in the log table.

```
$emailsent = confirmExists($mysqli, 'EmailLog', 'UniqueID', $v[emailid]);

if($emailsent == 0){
   //echo "Email has not been sent";
   $mail->send();
   $link->query("INSERT INTO `EmailLog` (`emailid`) VALUES ('$v[emailid]')");
}else{
   //echo "Email has been sent";
}
```

Comment: while this solved my immediate problem, it did not fix the root cause of the repetitious emails

Comment: Are these sent during page processing, or from cron? If the former, it's *really* common for browser plugins to cause multiple submissions of forms, so try in a clean browser.